# The extension of the url is different with formatted routes path and normal routes path in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, routes, pdfkit

i use ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.14.

I know that formatted routes are deprecated.
[No More Formatted Routes](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/27/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-no-more-formatted-routes)

For PDF generation with PDFKit i need an url like app/foo/bar.pdf. 
With formatted routes path i get this url:

```
link_to('foo', formatted_bar_foo_path(:format => :pdf))
```

But in the Controller i dont run into the format.pdf block, but into the js block, because it is first.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { ... }
  format.pdf { ... }
end
```

With the normal routes i get an url without .pdf extension (**app/foo/bar?format=pdf**), what i dont need, but run into the format.pdf block

```
link_to('bar', bar_foo_path(:format => :pdf))
```

What may i do to have this url **app/foo/bar.pdf** and run into the format.pdf block?

[EDIT1]

My route is:

```
map.resources :foo, :collection => { :bar => :get }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the routes

In your routes file

```
resources :bar
```

In controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { ... }
  format.pdf { ... }
end
```

Then you can do stuff like

```
/bar/1.pdf
```

Comment: I have specify the routes, the route is ->  map.resources :foo, :collection => { :bar => :get }